# Teradata update with left join and inner join

Tags: sql, join, sql-update, teradata

I need to bring the below sample code from mssql to Teradata. Please let me know how to convert it.Sample code -

```
Update table1
set table1.name = table3.name 
from table1 
inner join table2 
on table2.id = table1.id 
left join table3 
on table2.id = table3.id where table3.name is null
```

Comment: Why do you have `table3.name is null` in the `where` clause?  You are using that in the `update`.  Why not use an explicit `null` in the `set`?

Comment: Essentially, I want all the no match values after the left join to be updated to NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ugly, but this should work.  You can get around Teradata not allowing outer joins in an update by using a derived table.

```
update table1
from table1,
(select <column list> from table2 left join table3 on table2.id = table3.id) t
set ...
where
table1.id = t.id
and t.name is null
```

Comment: It seems I dont have enough reputation to accept the answer :(

Comment: I **think** you should be able to accept the answer (the checkmark) but not upvote it, with your current reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others mentioned, you should check your `NULL` condition.  Nevertheless, here's one more option:

```sql
Update table1
FROM (
  select table1.id, table3.name
  from table1 
  inner join table2 
  on table2.id = table1.id 
  left join table3 
  on table2.id = table3.id where table3.name is null
) src
SET table1.name = src.name
WHERE table1.id = src.id
```

You just move your original source query into a "src" sub-query and update from it.  Just make sure in your "src" query you only have one row for each `table1.id` value so you don't get `target row updated by multiple source rows` errors.

Comment: I think we need to include table1 as well in the from clause, otherwise its giving error code 3993 illegal usage of alias name

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is better handled by `not exists`:

```
Update table1
    set table1.name = null
    where not exists (select 1
                      from table2 join
                           table3 
                           on table2.id = table3.id
                      where table2.id = table1.id 
                     );
```

This is not *exactly* what your query specifies -- this will update `table1.name` when there is no match in `table2`.   If that is an issue, you can do:

```
update table1
    set table1.name = null
    where exists (select 1
                  from table2
                  where table2.id = table3.id
                 ) and
          not exists (select 1
                      from table2 join
                           table3 
                           on table2.id = table3.id
                      where table2.id = table1.id 
                     );
```